# path aliases in drupal 7

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I want to calculate the path aliases for array of nids. But it always give me the path for latest content. Actually I can not get all the nids. My array structure is like below. When I used the command `product_childnid = array_pop(array_keys($result['node']));` I always get the `100` nid but I want all of them for path aliases.

```
Array
(
[node] => Array
    (
        [78] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 78
                [vid] => 78
                [type] => product
            )

        [80] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 80
                [vid] => 80
                [type] => product
            )

        [82] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 82
                [vid] => 82
                [type] => product
            )

        [84] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 84
                [vid] => 84
                [type] => product
            )

        [86] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 86
                [vid] => 86
                [type] => product
            )

        [88] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 88
                [vid] => 88
                [type] => product
            )

        [90] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 90
                [vid] => 90
                [type] => product
            )

        [92] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 92
                [vid] => 92
                [type] => product
            )

        [94] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 94
                [vid] => 94
                [type] => product
            )

        [100] => stdClass Object
            (
                [nid] => 100
                [vid] => 100
                [type] => product
              )
          )
  )

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->entityCondition('bundle', 'product');
$query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$query->fieldCondition('field_product_sub_cat', 'tid',array($leaf_nodes));
$result = $query->execute();
if (isset($result['node']))
{
  $product_childnid = array_pop(array_keys($result['node']));
}
$path = 'node/'.$product_childnid;
$product_alias = drupal_get_path_alias($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ***iterate*** over all nodes in `$result` to do that. array_pop() only returns the last item in $result. So you'll have to do something like this:

```
$paths = array();
if (isset($result['node']))
{
  foreach($result['node'] as $key => $node) {
    $paths[$node->nid] = drupal_get_path_alias("node/$node->nid");
  }
}
```

After this `$paths` will contain an array of keys that map to each node id with a value that corresponds to its alias path.

Comment: Thanku @Shawn Conn, now I am getting all my paths but can you please explain me how can I represent this in my anchor tag?because I place it like this `<a href="<?php print ($paths[$node->nid]); ?>">` but it gives me the last path

Comment: Again, you have to **iterate** over the data. `$paths` will contain all elements because it is an array. You need to used a `foreach` to loop through the data.

Comment: FYI: You can save yourself a lot of trouble using the `echo l("TEXT", $paths[$node->nid]);` to print links.

Comment: `$title = field_get_items('node',node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE), 'title');` and then`print $title[0]['value'];` I have to link over this, is this possible with l function?